# Documents are not moving from Drop-Off library to Record center

Tags: sharepoint-online, records-center

I have configured the rule to move the document set content to the record center in the content organizer. But when we add the .zip file to  (Packaged) - the zip file stays back in the drop-off library, it does not go to the record library - when we upload the file in drop-off library we get the below message:

"**Moved to Drop Off Library
The document was submitted successfully. Its location will change pending action from a site administrator. For now, you can continue to access the document here:**"

I have checked in google, many links saying that it might happen when we don't feel the mandatory require column values which causes the data validation error, but I ensure that I have updated all column values, still, it does not move to the record library.

However, when we try uploading a document in the "Document" content type (a separate rule is configured for this) - it works fine, immediately it moves to the record library.

Any ideas why it does not work here?

**Note**:

We have also another site there also has a similar setup with the  (Packaged) content type in the dropoff library - there it works.

Any help will be much appreciated on this.

Comment: We are facing similar issue as the one describe above, were you able to resolve the issue?  What was the solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following tips to troubleshoot the issue.

Whether the "Target Path" in the same site or another site?

If the "Target Path" is in a different site, you should set a send to connection configured via SharePoint central administration -> More features -> Records management -> Send To Connections.

And another content organizer rule is needed in the target site since the send to connection does not include the target library, so documents will be left in the Drop Off library in the target site.

Reference:

[Copy/Move documents to different SharePoint site collection using Content Organizer.](https://unnieayilliath.com/2016/07/27/copymove-documents-to-different-sharepoint-site-collection-using-content-organizer/)